# Invalid object name 'dbo.MapLocations' error in my controller

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am coding a C# MVC5 internet application and I have both a `MapCompany` and `MapLocation` controller, with views.

My `MapCompany` model has a list of `MapLocations`.

Here is my context class:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> userInformation { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MapCompany> mapCompanies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MapLocation> mapLocations { get; set; }
}
```

I can successfully perform CRUD actions in the `MapCompany` controller. However, I cannot perform any actions with the `MapLocation` controller.

If I load the `Index()` method in the `MapLocation` controller, I get the following error:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.MapLocations'.
```

At this line of code:

```
return View(await db.mapLocations.ToListAsync());
```

May I please have some help with this code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your database table name?

Comment: Where do I find/specify that?

Comment: The error "Invalid object name 'dbo.MapLocations' is coming from the database server. It's looking for a database table named MapLocations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missed to create the table named **'dbo.MapLocations'** in your DB (May be missed any spelling) or you might have wrong connection string in webconfig.

The error clearly describes that there is no object in name of 'dbo.MapLocations' in your specified database server.

Please check your DB

Comment: Is there a console statement that I can use to totally recreate the database?